# How do I create a variable based on the counts of another variable, grouped by a certain key?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set which contains a label column and a task ID column. there are 3 rows for each task ID, each with some value of L1-L5 in the label column. I need to assign a final label to each task, based on specific combinations of these labels for the task. This looks like this:

```
- TaskID Label
- Task1     L1      
- Task1     L2      
- Task1     L5      
- Task2     L2      
- Task2     L2      
- Task2     L4      
- Task3     L1 
- Task3     L1 
- Task3     L1
```

I'm very new to python and stuck on how to code this - so far, I have created a new table that is grouped by task ID and label, with a count column, using `lCounts = df.groupby(['task_id','Label']).agg(['count'])`
so it looks like this:

```
- TaskID   Label  Count
- Task1     L1      1
- Task1     L2      1
- Task1     L5      1
- Task2     L2      2
- Task2     L4      1
- Task3     L1      3
```

and so on, but not sure if this helps or not. Ultimately, I need variable named `finalLabel` which is conditioned on the counts of each label for each task (e.g. if a task has 2 L2s and 1 L4, final label is A, if it has 3 L3's final label is B, if it has 1 L1, 1 L2, and 1 L3, final label is C, etc). I have a chart in excel that maps every label combo to a final label.

The output would be something like

```
- TaskID   FinalLabel 
- Task1     A        
- Task2     B      
- Task3     C
```

How can I best do this? I am stuck!

Comment: Hey Vee, welcome to SO, thanks for posting some sample code and an example of an output you tried. To make this reproducible we need a sample of your original data with an expected output.

Comment: Didn't I include that above? I'll try to make it clearer...

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: create a dictionary from your excel sheet with list as key and label as value

```
 d = {('L1', 'L3', 'L4'): A, ('L2', 'L2','L3'): B}
```

Step 2: create mapper for task:finallabel

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('TaskID')['Label'].apply(tuple).to_frame()
```

Step 3: map final list to each task and then map to dict

```
df_grouped['FinalLabel'] = df_grouped['Label'].map(d)
```

hope this helps.

EDIT:
You can write an assign function ass follows based on the counts of elements in the example.

```py
def assign_label(label):
    if len(label) == len(set(label)): # 3 different elements in label
        return 'A'
    elif len(label) - len(set(label)) == 1: # 2 differnet elements in label
        return 'B'
    else:
        return 'C' #all the same elements in label
```

```
df_grouped['assigned'] = df_grouped['Label'].apply(assign_label)
```

Comment: Thanks! What is 'Lbl' here?

Comment: Also, do I need for this dictionary to define the different orders for each label? Like L1, L2, L3 should be the same as L2, L1, L3, but will I need to define every combo separately? This was why I was hoping to do this with counts

Comment: I tried this, but got an error when trying to make d with a list as a key

Comment: I fixed the key error. Tuples are immutable so that should work. You said you have an excel that maps each label to a combo. If you save that as a tsv-file you can import this in python and convert to a dictionary. I do not understand how you define a final label. Post a list of final labels or snippet of excel with mappings. Then we can see how to generate this the easy way in python

Comment: I tried it with tuples after googling some things and it also didnt work. final label is just based on what combo (order doesn't matter) of 3 labels exists for the task. each possible combo results in a certain label.

Comment: Make sure to use apply(tuple). You can write a function for each combo and use apply on that combo.

Comment: can you elaborate? the problem is i don't have all the information in 1 row, there are multiple rows for each task